# Generate a diff for a change that moved a function between files, and also changed slightly?

Tags: git, diff

In a single commit, I moved a function to a new file, and also made some changes to it.

Github's diff viewer just shows ~30 lines deleted from the old file, and 30 lines added to the new file - it's hard to see what differences existed in the implementation of the old file and the new one.

Are there any tools that can help break down this diff? I can copy the relevant sections of each to a new file, and run `diff` on these, and generate a patch file I suppose...

Comment: When you say the github's diff, it's the line command or the UI ?

Comment: I don't believe so - fundamentally you're removing code from one file. You're adding code to another file. Git supports moving of entire files and maintaining the history, but not with segments of code that get transferred via your computer's clipboard.

Answer (score 1):

The command line `git diff` program has a heuristic for detecting renames but it is not turned on by default.  Enable it via the `-M[<n>]` or `--find-renames[=<n>]` option.  For example:

```
git show --find-renames <commit-sha>
```

As you have experienced, Git does not track renames.  The heuristic it employs is to compare files that were deleted and added for similarity.  The default *similarity index* is 50%, but this can be controlled with the `=<n>` argument.  To increase the threshold to 90% (the files must be 90% the same to be considered a rename):

```
git show --find-renames=90% <commit-sha>
```

If you want git to *always* detect renames, there's a config knob for that:

```
git config --global diff.renames=true
```

For more information see the [`git-diff` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff).